# 'float' object is not subscriptable when testing average in google colab

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

I want to test whether the average house price is greater than 100000

Using Z score because the data sample is large >= 30

```
import math
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest

stdev = 16518 
alpha = 0.05
null_mean = 100000 
Z_Score,p_value = ztest(sample['SalePrice'],value=null_mean,alternative='larger')
```

when i run it using google colab the result is an error but if i use jupiter notebook there is no error. can you guys find the problem?

Comment: What is `sample`?

Comment: sample = 1459/(1+1459 * 0.05**2)

Comment: So, `sample` is a floating point number, but you are trying to access `sample['SalePrice']` - that will cause the error you're seeing. It's unclear why Jupyter wouldn't cause an error on that, probably because `sample` has a different value and you're not seeing it correctly.

Comment: thanks for helping me and i have changed it then it worked. I use sample2 results from fulfilling the previous sample.

sample2 = data.sample(n=314)
sample2.shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sample` is a `pandas.Series` (as opposed to a `pandas.DataFrame`) then `sample['SalesPrice']` can be an arbitrary object rather than a collection of arbitrary objects. In your case it seems to be a `float` so it is not `value` but `x1` that your error is likely about.

I just tried your code with `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead of `sample['SalePrice']` and it worked fine for me.

Comment: thanks for helping me and i have changed it then it worked.